# C#: How can I detect the bitness of an other process... not the current one

Tags: c#, process, 32bit-64bit

How do I know the bitness of some process which is in running state. (Not the current one.. where IntPtr.size is useful) iswow64process()... gives only whether it is a WoW64 process, but doesn't output 32/64 bit.. could anybody pl help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`IsWow64Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms684139) is the right approach. Running under WOW64 is only true for a 32bit process on a 64bit OS.

Comment: So the full condition that works for me is: `var is32 = !Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem || (IsWow64Process(process.Handle, out var isWow64) && isWow64);`

Answer (score 4):

If you know you are running on 64-bit windows then if it a process is running in WoW64 mode then it must be 32-bit (that is what WoW64 is for - running 32-bit applications on 64-bit Windows), if not then you can assume 64-bit.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384249%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> WOW64 is the x86 emulator that allows
>   32-bit Windows-based applications to
>   run seamlessly on 64-bit Windows.

Also from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684139%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> [IsWow64Process] A pointer to a value that is set to
>   TRUE if the process is running under
>   WOW64. If the process is running under
>   32-bit Windows, the value is set to
>   FALSE. If the process is a 64-bit
>   application running under 64-bit
>   Windows, the value is also set to
>   FALSE.

Answer (score 3):

The real trouble is finding out that you are running on a 64-bit version of Windows.  Using IntPtr.Size isn't good enough, your program might have been forced to run in 32-bit mode.  You'll have to P/Invoke GetNativeSystemInfo() to get SYSTEM_INFO.wProcessorArchitecture.

Watch out for exceptions from these P/Invokes, the API functions are not available in XP and earlier.  When you get one from IsWow64Process then you'll know it is a 32-bit OS.  You can avoid the exception with LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress.

Comment: Since .NET 4, there's a much simpler way to do this: [`Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitoperatingsystem.aspx)